# OPTIONS request handler should be called before API handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, cors

I have a working @RestController component that yields API web endpoints.

This is one of those endpoints

```
  @CrossOrigin
  @GetMapping(API_VERSION + PLAYER + METHOD_FETCH + "/{uid:^[0-9]*$}")
  public Player fetchPlayer(@PathVariable("uid") String uid) {
    return mongoTemplate.findById(uid, Player.class);
  }
```

Now when using my Vue.js App I call this endpoint. The problem is the `axios` http client library turns a *get* request that has authentication headers into a *options* request to probe the server for actual access.

Now I need to consume this *options* request and have it be enabled for **CORS**. I did the following therefore:

```
@RestController
@Log
@RequestMapping("/**")
public class AuthenticationEndpoint {
  @CrossOrigin
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
  public void handleOptionRequest(){
    log.info("option request handled");
  }
}
```

I map it to every url so it "should" intercept every OPTIONS request. But it does not. When having a

```
GET http://{{host}}:80/api/v0.1/player/fetch/4607255831
Authorization: Basic MTIzNTM2NDMyNDphYmMxMjM=
```

The more specific API web endpoint is handled *before* the OPTIONS handler.
How can I actually put the OPTIONS handler *before* the others in Spring MVC?
I want it to act like an interceptor

**OR**

What is the best practise way to achieve the wanted behaviour? I kinda feel I am hacking around a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I actually put the OPTIONS handler before the others in Spring MVC? I want it to act like an interceptor.

Your can create a component a class that implements `Filter` interface and give it a High order :

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String httpMethod = req.getMethod();
        if(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equals(httpMethod)){
           //do something here before reaching the method handler
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    // other methods 
}
```

Or you can extends `OncePerRequestFilter.java` and make the same check as above in the `doFilterInternal` method.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to control whether to proceed handling a giving request or not you can use `HandlerInterceptor` :

> A HandlerInterceptor gets called before the appropriate HandlerAdapter
>   triggers the execution of the handler itself. This mechanism can be
>   used for a large field of preprocessing aspects, e.g. for
>   authorization checks, or common handler behavior like locale or theme
>   changes. Its main purpose is to allow for factoring out repetitive
>   handler code.
>
> HandlerInterceptor is basically similar to a Servlet
>   Filter, but in contrast to the latter it just allows custom
>   pre-processing with the option of prohibiting the execution of the
>   handler itself, and custom post-processing. Filters are more powerful,
>   for example they allow for exchanging the request and response objects
>   that are handed down the chain. Note that a filter gets configured in
>   web.xml, a HandlerInterceptor in the application context.

```
@Comonent
public class LoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
     @Override
     public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response,
                          Object handler)
                   throws Exception{
         // do checks and decide wether to complete or to stop here
         // true if the execution chain should proceed with the next interceptor or the handler itself. 
        // Else, DispatcherServlet assumes that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself.
        return true;
     }
     // other methods
}
```

Comment: Is this the way to do? Looks also just like a workaround. As I understood the OPTIONS requests it is probing if the host-resource is accessible at all. And after that returns a "true" state (?) it will do the real GET request. In a filter I cannot immediatly send back a "true" to the requester.

Comment: No this isn't the only way to achieve your goal , you can use spring HanderInterceptorAdapter, I'll update my response